# Facebook Graph API Missing Permissons Error (But i have permissons)

Tags: javascript, typescript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to get the user's access token with necessary permissons, then i use the token to get the page id i want to query, then i query that page to get the instagram account bound to it to no avail, i have all the permissons required (instagram_basic and pages_show_list) but it gives me this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) missing capability or permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "**************"
  }
}
```

I have all the permissions and i'm very sure the page i'm querying with and the instagram business account i have are bound together.

Do you have any idea on how i can fix this?

Note: I also tried replacing my User Access Token with that page's spesific Page Access Token, same problem, i tried seemingly everything by now

Answer (score 0):

To get access to a page, you then need to get a token access for the page in question. To do so you can use the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/accounts?access_token='your_app_access_token'
```

This will return all pages you have access to along with a page access token